# Running gradle's connectedAndroidTest on a specific device

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How do you run `connectedAndroidTest` on a particular device?

I would expect something like:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -DconnectedAndroidTest.device=XXXX
```

We have a number of devices plugged into our CI server and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to target a specific connected device.

`connectedAndroidTest` runs the tests on ALL connected devices currently.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like a future release according to this code snippet
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/160929/

Comment: Even though it was not possible by the time the question was asked, now it is possible and OP should consider changing the accepted answer. @MotohawkSF's response is now the correct one.

Comment: @JosefAdamcik Agreed and done.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Use the `ANDROID_SERIAL` variable

You can do this two ways:

#### 1. Set environment variable

```
# Set once; all following gradlew commands will use this
export ANDROID_SERIAL=1000AB0123456YZ

./gradlew <...>
```

#### 2. "Set" for just a command

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=1000AB0123456YZ ./gradlew <...>
```

If you set/exported ANDROID_SERIAL (method #1), you can use this to override that for a single command.

#### Note

This works with emulator identifiers (e.g., "emulator-5554"), too.

Comment: I have accepted this answer, because this is the new best answer.

Comment: @MotohawkSF you sir deserve a medal! 2 years ago we went through the pain to implement our own shell script and gradle task to run instrumented tests on specific devices (using adb -s) for our automated builds. If only we would have known how easy it is using your solution! Thank you!

Comment: this works for me also in the context of setting up runner of Gitlab

Comment: This solution is working in my local machine. When I run on build agents using the below task tests are running on emulator and on real device



`- task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        export ANDROID_SERIAL='emulator-5554'
        echo $ANDROID_SERIAL
        ./gradlew createQaDebugAndroidTest`

Answer (score 12):

It was not supported in 2014. The documentation for `connectedCheck` at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks, which delegates to `connectedAndroidTest` for these sorts of on-device non-UI-automated tests, explicitly states:

> Runs checks that requires a connected device or
> emulator. They will run on all connected devices in parallel.

There is a feature request (now marked as fixed) for the ability to select individual devices: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66129

Comment: Thanks for the link to the existing issue. On friday I read the source and discovered the same, but ran out of time to come back and answer the question.

Comment: According to the linked issue this is no longer true. The issue is actually fixed and there is now a way how to select devices and/or emulators to run the tests. Response by @MotohawkSF is a valid one now (and also works for me).

Answer (score 6):

I created an "hack" to be able to do it.. put this block in the `android` section of your *build.gradle*, and then you have to set the `ANDROID_HOME` env variable to the sdk folder, and the `UNIT_TESTS_DEVICE_ID` env variable with the serial number of the device on which you want to run tests on.

```
deviceProvider(new com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDeviceProvider(file(System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + File.separator + "platform-tools" + File.separator + "adb")) {
    public String getName() {
        return "singleDevice"
    }

    public List<? extends com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceConnector> getDevices() {
        List<com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceConnector> devices = super.devices;
        List<com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceConnector> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        String deviceSerialNum = System.getenv("UNIT_TESTS_DEVICE_ID");
        devices.each {
            if (it.getSerialNumber().equals(deviceSerialNum)) toReturn.add(it);
        }
        if (toReturn.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Device for unit tests not found!");
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
})
```

Then you use the task `singleDeviceAndroidTest{Variant}` to run the tests. Tested only on gradle plugin version 1.0.0.

Comment: still be usefull~ only the namespace was changed

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible now. Just set `ANDROID_SERIAL` environment variable to the device id you want your tests to run on.

Answer (score 0):

@MotohawkSF's answer did not worked for me in Android Studio terminal. What worked though was using the name of the device after running `adb devices`

```
> adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.22.122:5555    device
emulator-5554   device
```

then

```
set ANDROID_SERIAL=192.168.22.122:5555
gradlew someTask
```