# Can I run a gradle command on a specific device?

Tags: android, gradle, adb

I have a server that has two connected Android devices. I also have instrumentation tests and functional tests which are run with two different gradle commands. The functional tests will only run on one of the devices, and the instrumentation tests will only run on the other device. Both sets of tests need to be run regularly and unplugging/plugging in devices as needed isn't practical (I don't have physical access to the devices). Is it possible to run a gradle command so that it will only run on a specific device?

Comment: There is a (partial) relevant hint in this answer, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43502439/1531971 (The tests themselves can be associated with devices, apparently.)

Comment: Aha, I found it, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23960667/1531971 There are frameworks out there that purport to assist with this, but I have no idea if they address this specific issue.

Comment: set `ANDROID_SERIAL` variable and `adb` would use that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set `ANDROID_SERIAL` in the session you are running the tests. If you have two independent sessions that run each set of tests, one will have the ANDROID_SERIAL pointed to DEVICE_1 and in the other, to DEVICE_2. This can be automated on jenkins.